# Graphics error: Don't know how to automatically pick scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I am trying to use *ggplot* to create a plot of relationship of `nycflights13`, it shows following error, could someone help me to figure it out?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)

data=flights

mutate(data,
   delay=arr_delay - dep_delay)

p1 <- ggplot(data,aes(x=dist,y=delay))+
      geom_point(aes(color=count,size=count),alpha=1/2)+
      xlab("Distance")+
      ylab("delay")+
      ggtitle("Distance vs. Delay")+
      geom_smooth()+
      scale_size_area()

p1
```

**Error:**

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. 
Defaulting to continuous.

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for the object of type function. 
Defaulting to continuous.

Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (336776): colour, size, x, y
```

Comment: `count` doesnt seem to be in the `flights` dataset. `names(flights)`

Comment: it does not work

Comment: my comment was that you are passing a variable `count` to `geom_point`, but that `count` doesnt seem to be in the dataset. You can see this by using `names(flights)`

Comment: I misunderstand your sentence,sorry

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I wanna create a plot which shows the relationship between total delay time and the distance of flys.and the reason why I put color=count,size=count is that I want to color and size change with count –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed a number of issues with your code. Besides the wrong abbreviation of `distance`, the calculated `delay` values aren't saved anywhere. `mutate()` returns a tibble which must be assigned to a variable or piped.

Fixing these issues but neglecting `count` for a second, the code below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)
p1 <- flights %>% 
  mutate(delay = arr_delay - dep_delay) %>% {
    ggplot(.) + aes(x = distance, y = delay) +
      geom_point(alpha = 1 / 2) +
      xlab("Distance") +
      ylab("Delay") +
      ggtitle("Distance vs. Delay") +
      geom_smooth()
  }
p1
```

produces

[image]

---

#### Adding `count`

`count` is *no* variable (column) contained in the orginal data set. In [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834117/graphics-error-dont-know-how-to-automatically-pick-scale/44835999#comment76649474_44834318), the OP has tried to clarify "*the reason why I put color=count,size=count is that I want to color and size change with count*".

In a wild guess, I assume that the OP does mean the number of flights per distance but that he still wants to plot each individual flight with colour and size as additional attributes.

So, the number of flights for each distance has to be counted and to be added to each affected flight. This kind of computation has to be done before calling `ggplot()`. Here, I switch from `dplyr` to `data.table`as I'm more familar with the latter:

```
library(data.table)
p1 <- data.table(flights)[, delay := arr_delay - dep_delay][
  , count := .N, by = distance][
    , ggplot(.SD) + aes(x = distance, y = delay, color = count, size = count) +
      geom_point(alpha = 1 / 2) +
      xlab("Distance") +
      ylab("Delay") +
      ggtitle("Distance vs. Delay") +
      geom_smooth() +
      scale_size_area()]
p1
```

[image]

---

#### Aggregate by `distance`

The chart looks pretty cluttered, therefore I suggest to aggregate the data points before plotting

```
p1 <- data.table(flights)[, delay := arr_delay - dep_delay][
  , .(count = .N, delay = median(delay, na.rm = TRUE)), by = distance][
    , ggplot(.SD) + 
      aes(x = distance, y = delay, color = count, size = count) +
      geom_point(alpha = 1 / 2) +
      xlab("Distance") +
      ylab("Delay") +
      ggtitle("Distance vs. Delay") +
      geom_smooth()]
p1
```

which yields

[image]

Note that `median()` is used instead of `mean()` for aggregating delay times in order to reduce the impact of outliers.

The data still look quite noisy, so it might be worthwhile to consider to bin the distances:

```
p1 <- data.table(flights)[, delay := arr_delay - dep_delay][
  , .(count = .N, delay = median(delay, na.rm = TRUE)), 
  by = .(distance = round(distance, -1L))][
    , ggplot(.SD) + 
      aes(x = distance, y = delay, color = count, size = count) +
      geom_point(alpha = 1 / 2) +
      xlab("Distance, rounded to 10 miles") +
      ylab("Median Delay") +
      ggtitle("Distance vs. Delay") +
      geom_smooth()]
p1
```

[image]

Comment: You solved my question in essence!Thank you so much and I appreciated it!

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am little confused about code.in this sentence:"[
  , .(count = .N, delay = median(delay, na.rm = TRUE)), by = distance]" what is the meaning of ", .".And what's the difference between ggplot(.SD) and ggplot()? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: According to section 1.B of the [Introduction to data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) vignette, the general `data.table` syntax is `DT[i, j, by]` where `i` compares to the SQL `where` clause. If all rows are to be considered, we can leave out the `i` parameter but have to keep the positional `,`. In the expression `.(count ...)`, `.()` is an abbreviation for `list()`.

Comment: The `j` parameter can be any expression, including calls to arbitrary functions like `ggplot()`. However, `ggplot()` expects a data set to plot as first parameter. In `data.table` syntax, the special symbol `.SD` as used here denotes a `data.table` with all the additional columns computed so far.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of problems with variable names. The `x` aesthetic should be mapped to `distance`, and `y` needs to be `dep_delay` or `arr_delay`. `ggplot2` doesn't do partial matching of column names. Also, there is no `count` column as pointed out by @user20650.

This call is valid:

```
ggplot(flights,aes(x=distance,y=arr_delay))+
  geom_point(aes(),alpha=1/2)+
  xlab("Distance")+ 
  ggtitle("Distance vs. Delay")+
  geom_smooth()+
  scale_size_area()
```

Comment: how to fix it?Could you type some codes for me?thanks

Comment: I wanna create a plot which shows the relationship between total delay time and the distance of flys.and the reason why I put color=count,size=count is that I want to color and size change with count